# How to ensure security in Mobile Applications

Tags: asp.net, mobile, client-server, access-token

I am developing a front end mobile app for Android and iOS that interacts with my webserver that runs ASP.NET.  Right now, I am doing the following security measures:

1)Basic authentication
2)SSL using REST API
3)Store only a token on the device that is used to confirm with the server for future accesses

Anything else I missed??

Comment: possible duplicate of [The correct way of ensuring security on Mobile Applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788261/the-correct-way-of-ensuring-security-on-mobile-applications)

Answer (score 1):

I have some suggestions,

1. Use secure encryption/decryption algorithms like **AES-256 with password based cryptographic key**. Also **code obfuscation & jumble algorithms** can be applied for secure key generation to avoid reverse engineering attacks upto a level.
2. Disable caching of webservice request/ delete cache for each time. In iOS prevent caching of snapshots.
3. If you want to store Tokens on device you need to encrypt the token and don't depend authentication like sensitive web services relying on this token.
4. Define Session expire time according to your business needs and criticality.
5. Do not install or load application in Jail broken/Rooted devices.